# How is Record Zone Sharing done?

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit, sharing, ckrecordzone

My use case is the following:
Every user of my app can create as an owner a set of items.
These items are private until the owner invites other users to share all of them as participant.
Participants can modify the shared items and/or add other items.
So, sharing is not done related to individual items, but to all items of an owner.

I want to use CoreData & CloudKit to do CoreData/CloudKit mirroring and to have local copies of private and shared items.
To my understanding, CoreData & CloudKit puts all mirrored items in the private database in a special zone „com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone“.
So, this zone should be shared, i.e. all items in it.

In the WWDC 2021 video [„Build apps that share data through CloudKit and Core Data“](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10015/) it is said that `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer` uses *Record Zone Sharing* optionally in contrast to hierarchically record sharing using a root record.
In [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicloudsharingcontroller) to the `UICloudSharingController` an example is given how to share records using a `rootRecord`.
I assume this can be modified to use a shared record zone instead.
The `shareRecord` e.g. could be initiated instead with

```
let shareRecord = CKShare(rootRecord: rootRecord)
```

with

```
let shareRecord = CKShare.init(recordZoneID:)
```

But is this the ID of the record zone that uses Apple for mirroring, i.e. „com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone“? And if so, how do I get its `CKRecordZone.ID`, if I have only the zone name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By now I figured out how this can be done. Maybe it helps somebody else.

It starts with tapping a share button.
First, it is checked if a `CKShare` record already exists in the iCloud private database.
Depending on it, a `UICloudSharingController` is initialized either so that it created it, or so that it uses it.
If it should create the share, it is configured accordingly.

```
// See <https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicloudsharingcontroller>
@IBAction func sharingButtonTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let barButtonItem = sender
    
    /*
     If no CKShare record has been stored yet in iCloud, it will be created below using UICloudSharingController initialized with a preparation handler.
     If it exists already, UICloudSharingController is initializes with the existing CKShare record.
     */
    getShareRecord { result in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let cloudSharingController: UICloudSharingController!
            switch result {
            case .success(let ckShareRecord):
                if let shareRecord = ckShareRecord {
                    cloudSharingController = UICloudSharingController.init(share: shareRecord, container: CKContainer.default())
                } else {
                    cloudSharingController = UICloudSharingController { [weak self] (controller, completion: @escaping (CKShare?, CKContainer?, Error?) -> Void) in
                        guard let `self` = self else { return }
                        self.share(completion: completion)
                    }
                }
                cloudSharingController.delegate = self
                
                if let popover = cloudSharingController.popoverPresentationController {
                    popover.barButtonItem = barButtonItem
                }
                self.present(cloudSharingController, animated: true) {}
            case .failure(let error):
                fatalError("\(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}

// For sharing see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/shared_records
private func share(completion: @escaping (CKShare?, CKContainer?, Error?) -> Void) {
    if #available(iOS 15, *) {
        // iOS 15++
        let recordZoneID = CKRecordZone.ID(zoneName: "com.apple.coredata.cloudkit.zone", ownerName: CKCurrentUserDefaultName)
        let shareRecord = CKShare(recordZoneID: recordZoneID)
        
        // Configure the share so the system displays the shopping lists name and logo 
        // when the user initiates sharing or accepts an invitation to participate.
        CloudKitHelper.fullNameOfICloudAccount { result in
            var fullName: String!
            switch result {
            case .success(let name):
                fullName = name
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Could not read user name: \(error)")
                fullName = "Unknown user"
            }
            shareRecord[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.title] = String(format: NSLocalizedString("SHARING_LIST_OF_USER", comment:" "), fullName)
            let image = UIImage(named: kFileNameLogo)!.pngData()
            shareRecord[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.thumbnailImageData] = image
            // Include a custom UTI that describes the share's content.
            shareRecord[CKShare.SystemFieldKey.shareType] = "com.zeh4soft.ShopEasy.shoppingList"
            
            let recordsToSave = [shareRecord]
            let container = CKContainer.default()
            let privateDatabase = container.privateCloudDatabase
            let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: recordsToSave, recordIDsToDelete: nil) 
            operation.perRecordProgressBlock = { (record, progress) in
                if progress < 1.0 {
                    print("CloudKit error: Could not save record completely")
                }
            }
            
            operation.modifyRecordsResultBlock = { result in
                switch result {
                case .success:
                    completion(shareRecord, container, nil)
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(nil, nil, error)
                }
            }
            
            privateDatabase.add(operation)
        }
        
    } else {
        // iOS <15
        fatalError("Sharing is only available in iOS 15")
    }
}

func getShareRecord(completion: @escaping (Result<CKShare?, Error>) -> Void) {
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "cloudkit.share", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
    privateDB.fetch(withQuery: query) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let returned): 
            // .success((matchResults: [CKRecord.ID : Result<CKRecord, Error>], queryCursor: CKQueryOperation.Cursor?))
            let matchResults = returned.0 // [CKRecord.ID : Result<CKRecord, Error>]
            switch matchResults.count {
            case 0:
                completion(.success(nil))
                return
            case 1:
                let recordResult = matchResults.values.first!
                switch recordResult {
                case .success(let ckRecord):
                    completion(.success(ckRecord as? CKShare))
                    return
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(.failure(error))
                    return
                }
            default:
                fatalError("More than 1 CKShare record")
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(.failure(error))
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if you can use custom Zone IDs? So in case you have multiple databases you want to sync. Each database would have its own unique Zone ID. I know you can create zones with their own ID, but can Core Data CloudKit persistent container use custom zone IDs?

Comment: When you set up CoreData & CloudKit, the persistent store is configured with an `NSPersistentStoreDescription` object that has a property [cloudKitContainerOptions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcloudkitcontaineroptions). However, these options let you only select a container and a database scope. So there is no way to select a specific custom zone.

Comment: Ok thanks. So then there's no way to share an entire zone with anyone else. It has to be done with whatever zone CoreData uses. That's too bad. I think it would be great to let CoreData sync with a specific zone and to be able to share that entire zone with anyone.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped a lot. I can share data with a different iCloud user and any data the "sharing" user creates is automatically visibly for the user it was shared with as well. The issue I'm facing now is that any data the user that was "shared with" creates is not visible for the sharing user. How can I make the share bi-directional?

Comment: @PhilippJahoda This should normally work. However, share participants have a certain [permission](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckshare/participantpermission) that can be read only. In this case, maybe, the sharing participant can only modify its own data, but updates are not uploaded to iCloud. I have to say, this a wild guess. In my case, data modified by a sharing participant have always been uploaded to iCloud.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think in my case it's not "data modified" but new data created by the invited participant. Any new data the "inviter" creates is immediately visible for the "invited". However, any new data the "invited" creates is not visible for the "inviter". Any ideas are welcome :-)